# Putting vectors of different size in a matrix

Tags: matlab

I am trying to add a number of vectors in a Matrix where each row represents a vector, but it gives me "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch." error. The main problem is that each vector has a different size. I tried to add zeros at the end of the short vectors but I couldn't do it. Any Help.

Example:

```
%signal is a vector of data.
[x(1,:),y(1,:)] = findpeaks(signal1);
[x(2,:),y(2,:)] = findpeaks(signal2); %error as the peaks count in signal 2 is not the same as in signal 1.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, given two vectors of unequal length,

```
A=rand(1,10)
B=rand(1,5)
```

the proper way to deal with this is to use a cell array

```
D={A;B}
```

And then you can get whatever elements you want like this, for example:

```
D{1}(1:3) %// A(1:3)
```

If you don't want to use cells, you can add rows using this little function that adds row vector `M` to matrix `F`

```
addRow=@(F,M) [F NaN(size(F,1),size(M,2)-size(F,2));M NaN(1,size(F,2)-size(M,2))]
```

you would use it like this:

```
F=A
F=addRow(F,B)
```

Comment: Thanks David for the answer, but this will add the vectors in columns not in rows. I need to put each vector in one row and concate zeros if the size is smaller than the matrix size.

Comment: @SMH OK, I edited my answer. You really should use cells for this, but I'll update it to include the `NaN` array method.

Comment: is there is a way that I can concatenate a specific number of zeros to a vector?

Comment: I have a small question, can I use any variable instead of F while using the function even if I wrote F in the function?

Comment: @SMH Sure, just within the function the first argument entered will be referred to as ``F``, whereas the second argument will be referred to as ``M``. In the given example ``B`` is given as second argument but it will be referred to as ``M`` in the function.